# Python return json.dumps got error : TypeError: Object of type int32 is not JSON serializable

Tags: python, json

i want to return list like this example in json [[28, 73, 59, 29], [25, 58, 51, 25], [17, 60, 51, 25], []]

'temp_list_area_lips' is contain my data list what i want to send using "listAreaLips": list_area_lips in json.dumps.

**my code is like this :**

```
list_area_lips = temp_list_area_lips
print("bbbb", list_area_lips, "aaaa - ", type(list_area_lips))

return json.dumps({"faceDetected": face_detected, "listFaceUrl": list_face_url, "listFaceCategory":      list_face_category, "listAreaLips": list_area_lips})
```

**but it return error 'TypeError: Object of type int32 is not JSON serializable' like the image below**
[image: 1]
[image: 2]

**but if i assign list_area_lips manually like the code below, it can send data safely**

```
list_area_lips = [[28, 73, 59, 29], [25, 58, 51, 25], [17, 60, 51, 25], []]
print("bbbb", list_area_lips, "aaaa - ", type(list_area_lips))
return json.dumps({"faceDetected": face_detected, "listFaceUrl": list_face_url, "listFaceCategory":      list_face_category, "listAreaLips": list_area_lips})
```

so i check the data which i assign from variable and manually, but there is no difference type, the result like the image below

[image: 3]

how to send data list like this : [[28, 73, 59, 29], [25, 58, 51, 25], [17, 60, 51, 25], []] in return json.dumps? thankyouu

Comment: You have a list containing `numpy.int32` objects. That's pretty unusual, so there's probably something funky happening with how `list_area_lips` is being created. Without knowing how that was done, the best we can suggest is to convert those objects into ordinary Python `int`s: e.g. `[[int(e) for e in l] for l in ist_area_lips]`

Comment: @Brian thankyou so much... it works after i convert it..

Comment: What is your goal for converting to JSON? If you want to send a numpy array to another python program, or any program that can read other formats, there are other ways to do it.

Comment: @tdelaney i send the data to flutter using flask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Brian pointed out, you're trying to encode numpy instances which aren't serializable. IMO The easiest way forward is to add a custom JSONEncoder to your application.

```
class NumpyArrayEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, np.ndarray):
            return obj.tolist()
        elif isinstance(obj, np.integer):
            return int(obj)
        elif isinstance(obj, np.floating):
            return float(obj)
        else:
            return super().default(obj)
...

json.dumps(data, cls=NumpyArrayEncoder)
```

If you need to do this for flask, the implementation is similar:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask.json.provider import DefaultJSONProvider


class NumpyArrayEncoder(DefaultJSONProvider):
    def default(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, np.ndarray):
            return obj.tolist()
        elif isinstance(obj, np.integer):
            return int(obj)
        elif isinstance(obj, np.floating):
            return float(obj)
        else:
            return super().default(obj)


class CustomizedFlask(Flask):
    json_provider_class = NumpyArrayEncoder

...

app = CustomizedFlask()
```